# windows script to overwrite files with a certain name and ext

Tags: windows, bash-scripting

i have a folder with about 300 subfolder inside, in each subfolder there is some png file and i need to replace some of this file with an empty image created by me.

i want to place the script in the main folder (with the "Void image.png file also) and replace all the file with .png ext and "Bezel" in the file name with my image

complete file name have this layout "Bezel - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX .png"

i'm not a programmer, only have some basic knowledge 
i have created this but I do not know how to go on..

```
$FileList = Get-Childitem -path -recurse -filter "*.png";
foreach ($File in $FileList) {
    $File.Name -match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you should change your -filter to `-filter "*bezel*.png"`  so you are only getting a list of matching files. Then you can use the move-item commandlet.

Next, if you are trying to replace those files with a copy of another file, which is what it sounds like, you would do this:

```
$FileList = Get-Childitem -path -recurse -filter "*bezel*.png";
foreach ($File in $FileList) { move-item ".\yourfile.png" $File.Fullname -force }
```

Run the script in the top most folder with yourfile.png in the same folder and it will replace all files containing bezel in the filename and that have a .png extension with a copy of your file.

Comment: Aaargh, i was not so far from the solution :p
thanks man really appreciated!